Which is the best way to configure HTTPS on a Virtual machine
I am not an exepert with SSL topic. On my NAS synology, I installed Virtual Machine Manager and I created a new VM with Ubuntu with a small web server.

My VM received an IP address (192.168.1.147) from my home router. That local IP address is now reserved for my VM.
On my Home router, I forwarded the port 443 to my VM.
I also, I created a DDNS to access my VM with an customized url address (https://myvm.mywebsite.ch).
I seted up a reverse proxy to "tell" my NAS to redirect https://myvm.mywebsite.ch:443 to http://192.168.1.147:80

All works fine but I now need to install a letsencrypt certificate.
I can install a certificate on my NAS, but I wonder if it would be better to install the certificate to the Ubuntu (= in the virtual machine) with certbot.
My Ubuntu is into a VM of my Synology NAS, where I can install a certificate from the security->certificate tab for the personalized URL. Is this enough? or should I install the certificate "into" my Ubuntu/VM with certbot?
Thanks
